# Как передать звук с одного ПК на другой.

Tags: android, debian

Поставил Линукс Дебиан на кпк HTC Desire, пользуюсь им с настольного ПК(WindowsXP) посредством VNCviewer. Имеется вопрос: как организовать передачу звуков c Линукса на Windows? Соединение происходит по блютузу(PAN), скорость маленькая но со временем обзаведусь вайфаем.  На настольный ПК нет возможности поставить Линукс, а попользоваться хочется :), вот и извращаюсь. Буду рад помощи. Зарание спасибо.           Уточнение: Соединение между КПК и ПК происходит по блютузу, PAN протокол :). создается личная сеть между двумя устройствами. На КПК стоит VNC сервер на ПК VNC клиент. Требуется, организовать передачу звука с сервера на клиент.

Comment: простите,у вашего htc наверное есть провод,для подключения к пк?

Comment: И наверняка есть вывод на наушники :) Так что самый простой способ - кабелем типа джек-джек

Answer (score 1):

Варианты такие:

1. Записать файлы на флэш-карту
2. Подключиться по Wi-Fi

Если кпк под Debian нормально при подключении по шнурку нормально распознается, то качать данные по шнурку.

Comment: Там речь идет об удаленном управлении типа team viewer, radmin... Поэтому флэш-карта явно не катит

Comment: Нужно как нибудь транслировать звук с одного устройства на другое. Под словом звук я подразумеваю как бы выход со звуковой платы. В общем как то так )